# Enter "vertical bar" (or "pipe symbol") in Windows

Tags: keyboard, bootcamp, windows, internationalization

I have my MacBook late 2008 sometimes running Windows 7 via BootCamp. The keyboard has a German layout. Pretty much like the Wikimedia image below except that the blue symbols in the lowest line are not accessible.

[image]

*How could I enter the [vertical bar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_bar) `|` via my keyboard?*

Unfortunately <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> + <kbd><</kbd> does not seem to work. (However, I can enter `@` with <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> et al. as I can do on external keyboards.)

**Update2:** From what I can tell from the languages settings, the Windows layout is missing the <kbd><</kbd>-key between <kbd>Left Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Y</kbd>. What layout would provide it?

[image]

**Update 3:** On a co-workers current MacBook Pro its working as expected.

I'd also be happy with some comments suggesting ways to have it entered. I'm tiered of copying it from Wikipedia every time.

Comment: What keyboard layout are you using?

Comment: I assume you are German from your location, which keyboard exactly from the 4 keyboard layouts in the German (Germany) setup are you using in Windows?

Comment: With an external Swiss German keyboard `Alt Gr` (between space and windows keys) + `<>|` (next to left `Shift` key). Pressing `Alt Gr` + `§°` (top left / below `Esc`) worked, too.

Answer (score 7):

My US English Qwerty keyboard has it as <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>\</kbd>, with the \ key right above the Return key.

Comment: Unfortunately I have a German keyboard which does not this key.

Comment: Does it have a key next to shift that isn't Z?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with the German keyboard. Press the key <kbd><>|</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Strg</kbd> key together. It works!

You see, there is already the vertical line sign on the double arrow key if you notice clearly.

Answer (score 3):

Try

<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd><</kbd>

Re-reading your question, I looked at some standard German Keyboard layouts and you have the <kbd><>|</kbd> key in the bottom left hand corner of the layout.

The only issue you have is the right hand Alt (cmd) doesn't do anything different than the left one!

See the image to show where the keyboard is defined in Windows 7:
[image]
Edit: added screenshot of which keyboard layout (in English unfortuantely)

Comment: [CMD] does not change anything and so far I did not find another modifier that modified [ < ] the way I wanted.

Comment: I changed my keyboard within Parallels to a german layout, and tested this and it works, however I am using a UK Apple keyboard.  If you can please edit your question with the details asked (which exact keyboard layout you have selected in Windows) and which physical Apple Keyboard you are using

Comment: Where is this defined in Windows? (Also see update...)

Comment: added a screenshot to show where in Windows 7 the keyboard layouts are.

Comment: I look there after your previous comment. When I select any layout and check the "Preview" button, the `>` button between `Shift` and `Y` is always missing. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the `|` symbol by pressing <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> on a german keyboard layout.

Comment: That yields a `{` for me.

Comment: Mh thats strange. I'll look into it when i boot bootcamp later ..

Answer (score 3):

To get the pipe symbol(|) on UK keyboard with US input, press Alt key to the right of space bar + shift + backslash().

Comment: How does this answer the question? OP has a German keyboard with presumably German input.

Answer (score 2):

I think everyone's experience varies..on a us-keyboard on en-gb system:

```
right alt-key + '~' worked
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar problem with VirtualBox running Ubuntu and **Right** <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> worked - whereas **Left** <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> didn't.

Answer (score 1):

I have a HP laptop from the UK, after trying several combinations I finally found that <kbd>alt gr</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>|</kbd> (pipe) worked. No idea why it won't work normally in Linux!

Answer (score 1):

On my QWERTZ keyboard, it's the combo alt gr + w to get the |

Comment: Whats `gr` referring to here? The keys g and r? Or some meta key?

Comment: @Ian AltGr, shown next to the right Win button on the keyboard in the question.

Answer (score 1):

The missing <kbd><>|</kbd> key on my US keyboard when using Nordic language drove me mad and spent too much time stumbling around before fixing it with the help of On-Screen Keyboard and Power toys:

[image: Missing <>| key fix with On-Screen Keyboard and Power toys]

I found that someone had also already posted about it on SuperUser: [American keyboard with Swedish layout where is "pipe" and "tag" keys](https://superuser.com/questions/1524928/american-keyboard-with-swedish-layout-where-is-pipe-and-tag-keys)

So apologies for reviving an old thread but might save time for people struggling with this like I was.

Comment: Configuring Windows for Apple hardware is on topic @Alper. While other sites may be more familiar with Windows and able to provide better answers, it is still on topic here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a Mac Book Pro German keyboard via Microsoft Remote Desktop, and have just discovered **you MUST use the *right hand* Command + option keys** to get the equivalent Windows AltGr key!

[image]

```
                                                          ↓
```

[image: On screen keyboard with RIGHT HAND Command and option = AltGr depressed]

(This is why it has never worked for me for the last 20 years!)

Note: It helps if you turn on the on screen keyboard on the remote machine and then experiment pressing various modifier keys: The on screen keyboard shows you exactly the keys you'll get.

Answer (score -1):

I was working on Linux Mint Live on a USB I found out that its default keyboard was different when piping commands in terminal. I could guess that the tilde sign on UK qwerty keyboard is alternative for that (shift and hash sign next to ENTER key)

Comment: What do you recommend the OP to do to solve the problem stated in the question?

Answer (score -1):

my answer is alt+186 code or shift+(press key)

Answer (score -1):

Try this in Windows:  <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>4</kbd>.

To clarify, press and hold the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key and then in turn press the <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd> and <kbd>4</kbd> keys one by one. This should produce the | (pipe symbol) you're after.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different and thank you for your answer. :) Unfortunately, short answers such as this don't really provide enough detail or context to help many users. If possible, it'd be good if you could add some more info in this answer. For example, I could interpret your answer as meaning I hold down the Alt key and then simultaneously press the 1, 2 and 4 keys? Or, I could interpret it as holding down the Alt key and then pressing in turn the 1, 2 and 4 keys? It would be good if you could edit your answer (there's an _edit_ link below it) so that it provides enough detail.